# Argument Too Large - JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I've created a script in **Google's Apps Script** that creates Stripe Payment Links for my Client Database,
The problem is that i wanna pass the mail argument + subscription link in the HTTP Request.

The input is:

> line_items[0][price_data][currency]":"RON","line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval]":"month","line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval_count]":4,"line_items[0][quantity]":1,"line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]":"Name","line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]":31000,"[customer_email]":"test@test.com"

I have to pass this in

Cache.put(input, url, 21600);

**BUT Apps Script doesnt allow arguments > 250 Characters.**

Is it possible to:
make PUT Requests with multiple objects: put(input1,input2, url, 21600);

OR

Is it possible to shorten the input somehow? Because there are many strings that repeat themselves, like the following line_items[0][price_data] - Given that i have no access to the backend (Backend is Stripe)

OR

Is it possible to increase Google Apps Script max Argument size bigger than 250?

Thank you in advance

Source Code

```
const STRIPESUB = (amount, currency, description, customer_email) => {

  const input = {
    "line_items[0][price_data][currency]": currency || "RON",
    "line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval]" : "month",
    "line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval_count]" : 4,
    "line_items[0][quantity]" : 1,
    "line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]": description || "Name",
    "line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]": Math.ceil(amount * 100),
    "[customer_email]" : customer_email || "",
  };
  
  const cacheKey = JSON.stringify(input);
  
  const cachedLink = CacheService.getScriptCache().get(cacheKey);
  if (cachedLink) return cachedLink;


  const params = {
    cancel_url: STRIPE_CANCEL_URL,
    success_url: STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL,
    mode: "subscription",
    billing_address_collection: "required",
    "payment_method_types[]": "card",
    ...input,
  };

  const payload = Object.entries(params)
    .map(([key, value]) =>
      [encodeURIComponent(key), encodeURIComponent(value)].join("=")
    )
    .join("&");

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      payload,
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    }
  );

  const { url, error } = JSON.parse(response);

  if (url) {
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put(cacheKey, url, 21600);
  }

  return error ? error.message : url;
};
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, to be honest , I can not find any ressource talking about the max size of 250 in App's Google Script, can you share with us the reference of this information ? Or if you have any returned error about that do not hesitate to share it with us to be able to think about any other workaround

Comment: `CacheService.getScriptCache().put(cacheKey, url, 21600)` this is adding a key value pair to a cache.  The key is too long.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String)

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez - You can see the link sent from from James

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String)

Similar to repeated calls to "put", but more efficient as it only makes one call to the memcache server to set all values. The maximum length of a key is 250 characters. The maximum amount of data that can be stored per key is 100KB. The values will expire from the cache after 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Comment: Are the keys of `input` and the number of entries it contains always going to be the same?

Comment: @James, the following will always be the same: 
Currency,
Interval - Month,
Quantity

Comment: Two options - write a convert function that takes `input` and turns it into a similar object with much shorter keys (and then an unconvert function, if you need it).  The other option is to only send an array of values as the cache key, like `JSON.stringify(Object.values(input))` - but that will only work if you always get the same keys in `input`.

Comment: @lulian Tunea Hey, if James' answer addressed your question, I'd suggest posting it as an answer on this post so that if ever other community members ask the same question they would use this post as reference as well.